# how to make ssh fail if any parameter is wrong

Tags: linux, ssh

I'm using the command `ssh -i /home/ssh_keys/10_1_1_127 root@10.1.1.127 date` for checking the date on some other machine,

If some parameter is wrong, like the user, the ip or the identity file doesn't exists,
ssh asks for password

for example, if I write `ssh -i /home/ssh_keys/10_1_1_1277 root@10.1.1.127 date`
whilst `/home/ssh_keys/10_1_1_1277` doesn't exists, I get:

`root@10.1.1.127's password:`

I wanted to know if it is possible, and if so, then how to make ssh fail if some parameter isn't right, so ssh won't ask me for a password if I enter wrong parameters...

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All these changes should be done via `root` or a `sudo` enabled user.

In `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` set the following entries to no:

```
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
PasswordAuthentication no
UsePAM no
```

If you need help finding those specific lines, use grep:

```
grep -n "PasswordAuthentication" /etc/ssh/sshd_config
          ^^or whatever^^
```

This outputs the line number

Then restart `ssh`

`/etc/init.d/ssh restart`

or

`service ssh restart`

depending on your flavor of Linux.